# Why does the Glasgow Haskell Compiler report multiple type errors here?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, ghc

Consider the following Haskell code

```
module TypeErrors where
f xs = [True | _ <- repeat 0]
x = (x, x)
```

The Glasgow Haskell Compiler (version 7.8.4) gives three type errors. The second and third arise from the infinite type implied by line 3. The first is

```
TypeErrors.hs:2:32:
    No instance for (Num t0) arising from the literal ‘0’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
```

After commenting out line 3, the module compiles as expected. I'd like to understand better how GHC performs its miracles. So my question is:

> Why does GHC object to line 2 if and only if line 3 is present?

Comment: Because there are multiple errors...

Comment: I only get two errors (both on line 3) when I [try your code online](https://ideone.com/zhWQvD)

Comment: @sepp2k That's interesting. I notice that ideone uses GHC 8.0.1. I compiled with GHC 7.8.4. Maybe the bug (if it is one) has been fixed.

Comment: GHC 7.8.4 is pretty old. Maybe it had a bug regarding reporting warnings as errors if there were other errors.  Or maybe it's reporting it as a warning and you're just misreading? That line should certainly be resulting in a warning about defaulting an ambiguous type, in normal GHC operation.

Comment: Great question -- precise, minimal, all the details needed to try it ourselves. I upvote questions pretty rarely, but this one deserved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. I can confirm the behavior you describe appears in 7.8.4, but does not in 7.10.3, 8.0.2, 8.2.2, or 8.4.2, all of which have either zero or two errors, not zero or three.

Comment: The moral of the story is: keep your compiler updated.

Comment: I clearly remember an old GHC version (could indeed be 7.8) where the first error in a file often caused several false errors to be reported later on. In that period, I learned to ignore all the errors but the first one. This was fixed in newer compilers.